# How to load an Alloy project in Titanium?

Tags: github, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am new with Alloy in Titanium. I see a lot of Alloy's project in GitHub but i dont know how to load into my workspace.

I download a file's structure like this:

assets (folder)
controllers (folder)
models(folder)
styles (folder)
views (folder)
README
alloy.js
config.json

Just it. So when i try to import this content i get a message telling me this:
"Selected directory doesn't contain a tiapp.xml, timodule.xml, or module.xcconfig file."

What do i need to run these projects in my computer?

Thanks a lot and sorry my bad english :P

Comment: Are you downloading the folders individually?  There should be an option to download them as a zip file on the right side.  Usually that expanded zip will have what is needed.  With Titanium and example projects you need to be flexible.  Matching up the SDK the author used and sometimes small tweaks helps get things running easier.  Link to the project so we can see if anything is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Github and you are using titanium Studio there is a option to import Github projects to your workspace, You just go to File->Import->Git->Git Repository as New Project then you can select the url and copy the Git Repository url from here:

[image: Github repository Url]

Then you click finish in Titanium Studio and that's it.

If this is not the answer, then in the repository you can search for the missing files, like tiapp.xml is in the main folder with the manifest and README files.